# Windows server 2008 web edition with SQL Server (Limits?)

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

I've read through a lot of the material covering the limitations of windows web edition 2008, but I'm nervous about making the call to go ahead and use it.

One small point I noticed was that Web Edition doesn't support Remote Desktop Services... does this mean that we cannot remote desktop into the server to administer it?

Also I can't seem to find anything solid that talks about the ability to load SQL server standard or enterprise edition onto a web edition 2008 server. Is this possible? Are there memory limitations?

Thanks,
Jacques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Remote Desktop Services" is **very** different to Remote Desktop. Remote desktop (for 2 remote + 1 console users) is available in every Microsoft server OS since Windows 2000. 2k8 Web is no different.

As far as SQL server is concerned, I believe it's technically possible to install SQL Server with a minimum of fuss (For 2005 I believe you'll need SP3). HOWEVER, the big limitation is that the SQL server can **only** be used by the web server it's installed on. You can't install SQL Server on it and then use that SQL for other applications/servers.

Comment: Does that include SQL Enterprise or Standard?

Comment: @Jacques - I'm not sure. I would *assume* only Standard, as enterprise includes a lot of stuff that would be outside the Web Server licensing.